# while loop works twice on each iteration

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I need to find a number which determined by user between 1 and 1000 in an efficient way. It looks like it is working but I have an issue. Whenever the while loop iterates, it iterates itself twice and I cannot escape this situation. So I can't call it "fully" working. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 500, div = 250;
    char user;

    printf("Please determine a number between 1 and 1000 and then press enter. \n");

    scanf("%c", &user);

    while ((user != 'Y') && (user != 'y'))
    {
        printf("Is your number %d? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller and 'L' if it is larger. \n", num);

        scanf("%c", &user);

        if ((user == 'S') || (user == 's')) {
            num -= div;
            if (div != 1)
                div /= 2;
        }

        if ((user == 'L') || (user == 'l')) {
            num += div;
            if (div != 1)
                div /= 2;
        }
    }

    printf("The number you determined is %d!", num);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Edit : I couldn't put output example from CodeBlocks so now adding it from Ubuntu. Output is like:

> Please determine a number and then press enter.
>
> Is your number 500? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.  s
>
> Is your number 250? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.
>
> Is your number 250? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.  s
>
> Is your number 125? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.
>
> Is your number 125? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.  l
>
> Is your number 187? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.
>
> Is your number 187? Please enter 'Y' if it is, 'S' if it is smaller
>   and 'L' if it is larger.  y
>
> The number you determined is 187!

user3121023 has solved the issue. I think since it is a comment, I cannot close the question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I actually read that enter is also accepted as a char and also because it is not "y", it gets in the while loop and then gets its right value so the program works. I added the output from gedit, so what else can it be?

Comment: When I use it, it just repeats scanf until I enter a char instead of enter and when I enter a char and enter, it still does work twice. It looks more like the while loop has a problem since first printf and scanf works correct.

Comment: Oh, my bad... Sorry my head got a little blurry since. It works correctly now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 4):

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` will read *any* character, including whitespace.  So the next time through the loop, it reads the newline and keeps going.

You need to put a leading space in the format specifier to absorb and newlines in the input buffer.

```
scanf(" %c", &user);
```